# jQuery var returning object

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, object

I have a variable called `loopNum` which returns as an object in console. The other variables return as expected. Can anyone explain why this is happening? Thanks

**Script**

```
    // stores how many carousels there are
    var carouselNum = $('.carousella').length;

    // stores the product of number of carousels times the increment value
    var loopNum = $((carouselNum - 2) * -183);

    console.log('loopNum = ' + loopNum);
    console.log('carouselNum = ' + carouselNum);
```

**Console**

```
loopNum = [object Object]
```

Comment: Why are you passing jQuery `$` the results of your calculation?

Comment: Why do you wrap `$(...)` around the number???

Comment: @thesystem sooo true here :-)

Comment: @thesystem, [I don't think he's using enough jQuery at all](http://img180.imageshack.us/img180/3305/addanumbertoanothernumb.png).

Comment: @zzzzBov: Heh, that's funny. :)

Comment: I'm gonna go find a corner and sulk :P

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Don't wrap the `carouselNum` variable into a jQuery wrapper `$()` after assigning it. Try this:

```
var carouselNum = $('.carousella').length;

// stores the product of number of carousels times the increment value
var loopNum = (carouselNum - 2) * -183;
```

Comment: @ClintonGreen No problems, glad I could help :)

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a selector here:

```
 var loopNum = $((carouselNum - 2) * -183);
```

It should just be

```
var loopNum = ((carousel - 2) * -183)
```